# VueJS Get info that matches route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using VueRouter. I need my users to be able to see the data when they navigate directly to an individual business. In order to do so, I am trying to create this method that loops through my data and matches the route with a property value of the data.

I have the following method:

```
methods: {
    finalItem () {
      return this.businesses.filter((business) => {
        return business.link === this.$route.params.listing
      })
    }
  }
```

But instead of getting the returned business data I'm getting:

> boundFn

I also tried something like this:

```
finalItem () {
      return this.businesses.filter((business) => {
        return business.match(this.$route.params.listing)
      })
    }
```

but got the same issue.

Comment: Are you trying to access `finalItem`? Or `finalItem()`? You need to do the latter since it's a method

Comment: Good catch, that worked :) Though I'm having trouble accessing `finalItem().name`'s equivalent.

Comment: I changed it to be `computed` so I can use without the `()` and still having trouble accessing the properties.

Comment: Ah, it was because it was returning an array so I had to do `finalItem[0].name`... Thanks for the help, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Use `this.businesses.find` if you want a single result and not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `finalItem` is a method, if you try to access it like a computed property it will simply return the function definition for that method (thus the `boundFn`).

Change the method to a computed property:

```
computed: {
  finalItem () {
    return this.businesses.filter((business) => {
      return business.link === this.$route.params.listing
    })
  },
}
```

Otherwise, you'll need to actually call the method:

```
// in your component's script
console.log(this.finalItem());

// in your template
{{ finalItem() }}
```